# Add method extremely slow

Tags: codefluent

Somewhere along the way (updating codefluent or the model growing) adding/editing a method got extremely slow. Opening the CFQL window takes almost three minutes. I have a fairly fast desktop (Intel I7-2600 @3,5 Ghz, 4Gb DDR3 ram, RAID array of 4 SSD's in RAID0).

I use Visual Studio 2015 update 1. The only plugin I have is ReSharper 10.1.

If I make a new sample advertising project it has the same latency so it does not seem to depend on the model.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have the same performance issue with the portable modeler (`C:\Program Files (x86)\SoftFluent\CodeFluent\Modeler\CodeFluent.Modeler.Portable.exe`)?

Comment: No that works like a charm

Comment: For diagnostic purposes I installed VS2015 and Codefluent on my laptop (also Windows 10) too. No performance issues yet. I'll update VS2015 with all upgrades and install Resharper and see how it works. I'll keep you posted...

Comment: BINGO! Resharper does cause the problem. After installing Resharper 10.0. I have exactly the same performance issue on my laptop. However, Resharper is a commonly used tool so propably I'm not the only one with this problem. Can you contact them or investigate?

Comment: I'm not sure this is only related to Resharper. I also have a Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 (Community) with Resharper, and I don't have the issue.

Comment: Please confirm you will investigate this issue. It's been a week since I posted the message...

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with Visual Studio 2015 Entreprise and Resharper, so I will investigate.

Comment: The version 838 of CodeFluent Entities seems to solve the issue: *TFS7617 - Modeler :  CFQL method editor loading performance has been improved.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The version 838 of CodeFluent Entities seems to solve the issue:
>   TFS7617 - Modeler : CFQL method editor loading performance has been
>   improved. – meziantou Jan 20 at 8:55

Version 838 DOES solve the issue indeed. Thanks!